# Serialization of EntityFramework LINQ Objects

Tags: linq, object, serialization

Gurus,

I want to serialize the Entityframe Work object (underlying object is from Oracle table). I'm using the LINQ Query.

Code Snippet

```
    using (Entities1 ctx = new Entities1())
    {

            ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;                    
    var oraLINQ1 = from ime in ctx.INV_MOVE_EVENT
                               select new
                               {
                                   ime.TO_POS_SLOT
                               };
                var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Stream stream = File.Open("INVMOVEEVENT.ifl", FileMode.Create);
                bformatter.Serialize(stream, oraLINQ1);
                stream.Close();
       }
```

I get an exception

```
"Type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[[System.String, 
 mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], EntityFramework,
 Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'EntityFramework,
 Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as 
 serializable."}    System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}
```

I tried INV_MOVE_EVENT entity class inheriting ISerializable. It didn't work. Any clues pointing to the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: so `TO_POS_SLOT` is the Entity? because you are trying to serialize a collection of `TO_POS_SLOT` not `INV_MOVE_EVENT`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I'm not clear. Can you help me with the correction in the code.

Comment: what type of object is `TO_POS_SLOT`?

Comment: TO_POS_SLOT is a string member in the IM_MOVE_EVENT Class.public string TO_POS_SLOT { get; set; }

Comment: Can any help me on the question?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it here in my side, but have you tried to convert the query to a list?

```
 using (Entities1 ctx = new Entities1())
    {

            ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;                    
    var oraLINQ1 = from ime in ctx.INV_MOVE_EVENT
                               select new
                               {
                                   ime.TO_POS_SLOT
                               };
                var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Stream stream = File.Open("INVMOVEEVENT.ifl", FileMode.Create);
                bformatter.Serialize(stream, oraLINQ1.ToList());
                stream.Close();
       }
```

It should work fine.